# Ionic 4- User's position tracking in Background

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, background-process

I'm working on an Ionic4/Angular app, and I'm trying to implement user's position tracking in background.

I tried 2 methods on android device:

- using [cordova-plugin-background](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) plugin but the geolocation's tracking is killed after 5 min in background
- using [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) plugin but the cordova [geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) cannot get positions in background

In both cases, I added those permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Any thoughts to fix one of the methods?

Comment: At least in Android those are the permissions needed  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Ok thanks ! It doesn't fix the problem but it's a good start

Answer (score 0):

You need to see this plugin

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt.git

This is perfectly works for me.